# query multiple SQLalchemy ORM

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm new in SQLalchemy I need to calculate multiple of some `price` in my one of the table. This is my tables:

```
class Order(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = Field(Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = relationship("OrderProduct", back_populates="order", lazy='dynamic')
```

and

```
class OrderProduct(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'order_products'
    id = Field(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('order.id'), nullable=False)
    order = relationship("Order", back_populates="products", protected=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    product = relationship("Product", back_populates="order_product")
    quantity = Field(Integer, nullable=False)
```

and

```
class Product(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = Field(Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = Field(Integer)
    order_product = relationship("OrderProduct", back_populates="product", protected=True)
```

I want to multiple `price` with this situation `OrderProduct.quantity * Product.price` and `products` in `Order` table is an array of `Products`

I write `SQL` query like this and it works:

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) FROM product
JOIN order_products ON product.id = order_products.product_id 
JOIN order ON order_products.order_id = order.id;
```

I tried to make it in ORM like this but it takes me `Product` and I can calculate only `price` without multiple in `quantity`:

```
    result = 0
        for product in Product.query\
            .join(OrderProduct).filter(Product.id == OrderProduct.product_id)\
            .join(Order).filter(OrderProduct.order_id == self.id):
        result = product.price + result
    return result
```

I make this as `@hybrid_property` and its work well.

I use a framework that name is `restfulpy`. it has ORM for sqlalchemy, `session` in this framework is `scoped_session`, but it gives me SQL query in debuging mode instead of executing the query like this :

```
sum_price = {Query}SELECT sum(product.price * order_products.quantity) AS sum_1 
FROM product JOIN order_products ON product.id = order_products.product_id JOIN "order" ON "order".id = order_products.order_id 
WHERE product.id = order_products.product_id AND order_products.order_id = :order_id_1
```

Well, Can anyone help me out this problem?

with regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that SQLalchemy is a great ORM! When you have a relation between two, three or ... tables, SQLalchemy make a join between them and you just query it!

I made it hard for me and my friends :) SQLalchemy is powerful than what I'm thinking!

This is the right answer:

```
@hybrid_property
def total_price(self):

return DBSession.query(
        func.sum(Product.price * OrderProduct.quantity))\
        .filter(OrderProduct.product_id == Product.id) \
        .filter(OrderProduct.order_id == self.id).scalar()
```

> `DBSession` is the same with `session`

Comment: you must add some filter to get specific product

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import func
query = session.query(func.sum(Product.price*OrderProduct.quantity))
               .join(OrderProduct).filter(Product.id == OrderProduct.product_id)
               .join(Order).filter(OrderProduct.order_id == self.id)
```